# Blank or Wrong Picture from EMGU capture

Tags: c#, video, emgucv

I am developing a windows service which processes video input and sends results of interest to a separate platform. I do not need to display the frames in this context. I am having a problem getting the correct camera input.

I want to save a Bitmap resulting retrieved from am EMGU capture object. To make sure that the capture is actually reading the video stream, I save the bitmap to a file, as follows:

```
Mat frame = mCapture.QueryFrame();
Template = frame.Bitmap;
Template.Save("frozen.jpg");
```

The capture is initialized as follows:

```
CvInvoke.UseOpenCL = false;
int index = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Index"]);
mCapture = new Capture(index);
```

One test platform is a Lenovo laptop running 64-bit Windows 10, with a built-in camera and a second camera attached through a USB port. The input of interest is the second camera. However, whatever index I use to open the Capture object, the input comes from the built-in camera.

The other platform is a Meego Pad, running 32-bit Windows 10, with the same camera attached. In this case, I simply get blank frames as video input.  For both platforms, running the camera application shows the video input as expected. What is the problem with my initialization of the Capture object?

**Further Investigation Shows...**

First, I was using the wrong index to create the capture, so that created some of the confusion. But more confusion follows.

When I call the QueryFrame() method in an event delegate, as shown in [this simple example](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Camera_Capture_in_7_lines_of_code) I successfully retrieve the frame from the camera. Example code looks like this:

```
Application.Idle += new EventHandler(delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  //run this until application closed (close button click on image viewer)
   viewer.Image = capture.QueryFrame(); //draw the image obtained from camera
});
viewer.ShowDialog(); //show the image viewer
```

When I call the same method in a different thread (in response to a communication event) I get an empty image. On the gripping hand, when I call the method in a timer callback, I get the correct image.

I won't call this closed, because I would still like to know why QueryFrame() acts correctly in some threads, but not in others. However, I can work with this, so the question is now mostly academic.

Comment: I don't think I can answer your question, but if you are using a new version of EMGU, you might want to look at the Capture.ImageGrabbed eventhandler instead. You control it with Capture.Start() and Capture.Stop(). Remember to use Retrieve() instead QueryFrame() in the ImageGrabbed event.

Comment: I tried that and got the same (wrong) camera input...

Comment: @AharonManne did you ever resolve this? I'm running into the same thread issue with EMGU and am looking to save some time on the "academic" part. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't resolve it, but I also learned that EMGU has problems with 2 cameras connected through a single USB hub. I don't know if that's relevant for you.